# Do you know how to turn these into single sentences per line?

Tags: microsoft-word

The sample is below. It is repetitive to press backspace and enter every time.

> Judging from these features, we can imagine that human ancestors
>   started polygynous or monogamous social structure with no or faint
>   sign of estrus. Gorillas in the wild usually avoid human observers. I
>   started working with wild Western Lowland Gorillas since 2003, at the
>   Moukalaba-Doudou National Park in Gabon. Today, I talk about the
>   habituation of gorillas and explain how we habituated wild Western
>   Lowland Gorillas.

Comment: Hmmm.  If you don't type the space after the **.**, then you don't need to press backspace.  But, if you already have text that's structured as one long paragraph (i.e., with spaces between sentences), beware that, in general, this is a very hard problem; see [How to put sentences on separate lines on Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190985/23408) (on U&L, naturally) for a lot of ideas on approaches to getting this right, and pitfalls to watch out for.  For example, you'll want to insert ¶ after `!` and `?` also, but not abbreviations (like "Mr. Spock" or "e.g.").

Answer (score 2):

In the find and Replace Dialog,

1. mark "use wildcards"
2. in "Find what" put a point sign and a space `.`
3. in "Replace with" put `.^p`(caret char p)
   [image: to split sentences into paragraphs]

This will replace the point space with point paragraph, in case that you want a new line use `^l`(caret char l) instead of `^p`

If you want to make lines of at least X characters long, then you can use the following:

1. mark "use wildcards"
2. in "Find what" put `<?{60,}`(After the closing curly bracket there is a space; The 60 is for at least 60 characters long before an space, the "<" sign indicates beginning of a word)
3. in "Replace with" put `^&^p`
   [image: to split into lines of at least X chars long]

HTH

> 11.22.2015 edition (Square brackets and notice have been removed, thanks to the kind advice of @Burgi)

Comment: Can you edit your answer and remove the square brackets? You can use [backticks](http://superuser.com/help/formatting) to identify your suggested user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

With Word **Find and Replace** it is easy to do.

- In the **Find What:** enter a dot and a space
- In the **Replace With:** put a dot and then ^p
- Then click **Replace All**

[image]